# How do i know which item in the listview is clicked when a button on my listview is clicked?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `listview` ,each item in my `listview` has a `textview` and a `button`. Now say I click the `button` on the second item in the `listview`, how can i detect if the `button` that was clicked belonged to the second item in the `listview`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your button `OnClickListener` in `getView` method of your adapter, then you will know the position with first argument:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    // Inflate your layout...

    Button mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Button clicked at position " + String.valueOf(position));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `onListItemClick()` to trigger list item listeners. See [this link](http://javarticles.com/2015/03/android-listactivity-onlistitemclick-example.html) for more information. Basically you have to:

1. Extend `ListActivity` or `ListFragment` depending on your class
2. Override `OnListItemClick()` method.